# Microsoft's Graph API request is producing incorrect headers

Tags: vue.js, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-mail

My app opens up a specific email within a shared inbox through some Vue.js code.

```
await this.$msal.msGraph('....inbox....$search="' + searchVal + '"');
```

If this email contains an attachment, maybe half the time the PDF will open normally and the other times it opens an Outlook window instead.

While looking at the request headers it seems like the request does not finish?

```
The working request... (id and token are large strings)
Request URL: https://attachments.office.net/owa/..../service.svc/s/GetFileAttachment?id=.....&token=....&owa=outlook.office365.com&scriptVer=20201130001.11&isDownload=true&animation=true&isDocumentPreview=True   
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200
Remote Address: ....
Referrer Policy: no-referrer

The broken request...
Request URL: https://outlook.office365.com/mail/&isDownload=true&animation=true&isDocumentPreview=True  
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200
Remote Address: ....
Referrer Policy: no-referrer
```

Thank you.

Comment: I see that you get PDF as attachment from the messages, but what type of attachment you're using here when you face the issue (file or item or reference)?

Comment: @Dev All appears the same, visually it is still a PDF attachment, and it still opens up as if it was an attachment, with the title of the file too... But only to show the inbox within this opened preview.

Comment: Ok @Adis, so the Graph API returns the PDF. But it doesnt show as you expected, right? Just see if you're using the following [Graph API call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/attachment-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) or different?

Comment: Yes that is right @Dev, and that is the same API, in fact this is quite similar to what i'm using to get all read requests on the inbox [Graph API Call Message Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript). I presume the ID retrieved from the ReadMail call, it could be used to fetch the attachment but I may need redevelop the front end for similar email accessibility, if I understand how it works.